# UINavigationController shouldAutorotate is returning YES

Tags: ios

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported
>   orientations has no common orientation with the application, and
>   [UINavigationController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011253ec65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00000001121d7bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000011253eb9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205     3   UIKit
>
>   0x000000010e3843d8 -[UIViewController
>   __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 644   4   UIKit                               0x000000010e379673 -[UIViewController
>   _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenStatusBarAndDeviceAndOrientation:] + 64    5   UIKit                               0x000000010e28b930 -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 103     6   Masafi_Universal                    0x000000010cda01a2 -[MasafiAppDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 8674    7   UIKit
>
>   0x000000010e23a748 -[UIApplication
>   _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 240  8   UIKit                               0x000000010e23b357
>   -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2540   9   UIKit                               0x000000010e23e19e -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349   10  UIKit                               0x000000010e23d095 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
>     11  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001136a95e5
>   __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21   12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011247241c
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12  13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112468165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341    14  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000112467947 __CFRunLoopRun + 887   15  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000112467366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     16  UIKit
>   0x000000010e23cb02 -[UIApplication _run] + 413    17  UIKit
>   0x000000010e23f8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282   18  Masafi_Universal
>   0x000000010ccc8a9f main + 111     19  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000112a4e145 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

This Exception is occurring while setting RootViewController  for window.

```
[self.window setRootViewController:dummyNavController];
```